# Filter xml using java

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml file with data.I need to create a xml report with some condition

eg:
Source xml file contains data looks like below

```
<testcase time="71.588" name="LifeActuarialRisk">
  <properties>
   <property name="Upload_" value="P"/>
   <property name="Upload_" value="P"/>
   <property name="Upload_" value="F"/>
   <property name="Upload_" value="P"/>
   <property name="Upload_" value="P"/>
  </properties>
</testcase>
```

I would like to filter the xml as below

```
<testcase time="71.588" name="LifeActuarialRisk">
 <properties>
  <property name="Upload_" value="F"/>
 </properties>
</testcase>
```

Could anyone can explain the solution

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

Use [JAX-B](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) to marshall & Un-marshall data,

**TestCase domain Class:**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class TestCase{

    private List<Property> logProperties = new ArrayList<Property>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="properties")
    @XmlElement(name="property")
    public List<Property> getLogProperties() {
        return logProperties;
    }
}
```

Also, write one for your `Property` class.

**Un-marshall, Transform & Marshall it to File:**

```
File file = new File("C:\\yourData.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestCase.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
TestCase aTestCase = (TestCase) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

aTestCase.setProperties(aTestCase.getProperties().stream()
.filter(p -> "F".equals(p.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));

Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(aTestCase , file);
```

Comment: Corrected it. That was a typo from my old code ;)